# should I detach action after attaching?

Tags: c#

I'm attaching action like that in constructor:

```
model.DataArrived += new Action<List<ConsoleData>>(model_DataArrived);
```

Should I detach it in `OnDispose`? Is it ok to create a new instance like that?

```
protected override void OnDispose()
    {
        model.DataArrived -= new Action<List<ConsoleData>>(model_DataArrived);
```

Or I should detach exactly the same instance that I've created in constructor? Should I keep this instance in private field only for detaching purposes?

Comment: What's `OnDispose()`? Do you mean `Dispose(bool)`? If so, you need to do it inside the `if (disposing)` check.

Comment: And you may write it shorter "model.DataArrived += model_DataArrived;" and similar for -=. Not an answer to the question, but an improvement thanks to the answer...

Comment: @SLaks i meant `System.IDisposable.Dispose()`

Comment: @erikH thanks, with such improvement question is answered automatically

Comment: Note that's just shorthand for what you're already doing; it isn't any different.  (it's new to C# 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fine.
Delegates are compared by value, not by reference.

The `Delegate.Remove` method, and the corresponding `-` operator, remove the last *matching* delegate from the first operand.

You only need to remove the handler at all if `model` will live longer than your object.  If so, the event in `model` will keep a reference to your object, keeping your object alive for too long.

Comment: You may want to read my [blog post on multicast delegates](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/08/delegates-vs-function-pointers-addendum.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I detach it in OnDispose?

Yes. Otherwise the model instance would keep this instance from being collected.

And as Slaks answered, the `-=` notation is fine.